# How to check if a value exists in an array-like object (javascript)

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am working with a firebase database which is returning an 'array-like' object.  Is there a way to check if a value exists on any field without looping through and checking each value.

My object looks like this:

```
{
  0: 44,
  1: 23,
  2: 16,
  3: 31
}
```

and I want to push another random number to the object but I need to check whether or not it exists first.

Comment: What have you tried so far? And basically you want to check if a match is found, if not then you want to add it? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35948669/how-to-check-if-value-exists-in-object-using-javascript

Comment: `var isValuePresent = Object.values(myObject).indexOf(valueSearchingFor) > -1`

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl You have move your comment into answer.

Comment: @VladimirKovpak This is why I have included the URL into my comment since Mr.Polywhirl decided to remove the url and just post the answer.

Comment: @NewToJS Sorry, question is closed. If you vote to close, it is good etiquette not to add an answer to the question. There was already a question that existed on this subject matter.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl I know. I have linked to the same answer you decided to copy/paste from... No reason to say sorry to me. I didn't just try take credit for an existing answer.

Comment: @VladimirKovpak Guess I responded to the wrong person…

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl It's ok!) i saw your reply...