# Jquery Check for key or value in array object

Tags: jquery, arrays, object

I'm using AJAX to retrieve data via php.
The resulting object available to Jquery looks like this:

```
Object {1234: "Martin", 4567: "Alf", 8512: "Symon"}
```

using the following I can get the key:

```
if ('4567' in staff)
    console.log('found')
```

How would I check if `Alf` exists ?

I've tried inArray, indexOf and various other examples, but I've not managed to get this working.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if value exists in object using javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35948669/how-to-check-if-value-exists-in-object-using-javascript)

Comment: The only way you can do that is loop through the values of Object and find if it has the value. Unless you want to use ES7

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I check if an object has a property in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/135448/how-do-i-check-if-an-object-has-a-property-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use JavaScript reflection as following:

```
var obj = {1234: "Martin", 4567: "Alf", 8512: "Symon"};

var find = function(input, target){
    var found;
    for (var prop in input) {
    if(input[prop] == target){
        found = prop;
    }
    };

    return found;
};

var found = find(obj, 'Alf');

if(found){
    alert(found);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8oheqd3j/