# How to find a object value from prototypes

Tags: javascript, json

Is it possible to make a function that can find from an object's prototype?
How do you find the value "5" on the Object's prototype and what is the right algorithm to use?

```js
var rex = {
"Name": "rex",
"Age": 16,
}
te = {
 "to": 5,
}

rex.te = Object.create(te);

function find(a,b){
 console.log(rex.te.to);
}
find(5,rex);
console.log(rex);
```

How do you find the value "5" on the Object's prototype?

Comment: how do you find it?? Basic object reference?

Comment: if you have defined the properties in a plain object and access that object directly then there is no prototype to speak of. Age: `rex.Age`, to: `rex.te.to`

Comment: @E.Sundin no, It doesn't need to use direct calling.. What I want for the script to do is find the value inside the object...

Comment: So loop over the keys

Answer (score 1):

What you are showing aren't the prototype of an object. They are just the objects values. Prototypes are essentially default functions that already exist on an object.

If you want to find if the object has a value which is 16 you will need to loop through it and check each key value peer.  There are also some other answers here: 
[How to check if value exists in object using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35948669/how-to-check-if-value-exists-in-object-using-javascript)

Comment: hello, I updated the code .. thank's for pointing that out.. Just added the right syntax.. can you check the code again?

Comment: The edits you have made don't really make any sense. You are creating a function called find and expecting it to find those values for you?  Also you are creating an object on the other object?  

You need to go back and clarify your understanding of javascript because I think reading the documentation is confusing you.  

Visit codeacademy.com. It's a good starting point for getting your head around the language and makes learning it really easy.

Answer (score 0):

```
function findVal (val, obj) {
    for (let key in obj) {
        if (obj[key] === val) {
            return key; // Assuming you want the key, not the value
        }
    }

    return null; // If value doesn't exist on the object, return null
}
```

Comment: Hello @monners the script is great but the algorithm is not quite right.. the script you shared is currently not outputing the right value...

Comment: If you want the value, just change `return key` to `return obj[key]`

Comment: you could use Object.values and includes on the resulting array... `Object.values({a:1,b:2,c:5}).includes(5) === true`