# String matches/includes/exists in Map

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Is there any option to check is string value exists in [JavaScript Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) structure and if it does, take the necessary key value?

For example:

```
let string = 'James never fly to Dubai'

let exampleMap = = new Map([
    ['Sasha', ' goes to school'],
    ['James', ' goes to college'],
    ['Kevin', ' goes to work'],
]);

if (string.includes(exampleMap.entries())) { //we get index value of match
    /* and (string) James + (exampleMap[1])goes to college*/
}
```

As for now, I'm using this code:

```
for (let [value, index] of exampleMap.entries()) {
   if (string.includes(value)) {
      console.log(string + index);
   }
}
```

But according [to this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/entries) and a [relevant answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57944826/7475615) for `Object` there should be an elegant one liner but I can't figure it out.

> UPDATED: I'd like to thank everyone who propose their idea below, I mark this question as answered, but let's be honest there are various ways to achieve necessary result. And my mark a «accepted as answer» is a bit subjective. So for all the Stackoverflow community, I believe that every proposed variant will be rewarded by their contribution.

Comment: `exampleMap.get(string)`?

Comment: @VLAZ Oh sorry, I forgot to mention a detail. Not it's more relevant to my case. So `get` by key not an option in my case, cause `string` never exactly the same as a Map(key)

Comment: OK...you could do it as a one liner but I wouldn't call it elegant. You have to materialise the entire `entries` iterator, then filter, then work with the filtered results. The problem is that you're looking for an overlap, not an exact match.

Comment: @VLAZ, well, yeah somekind of. It should be like a `lookbehind` where I found does one of key values in `Map` have a match with `string` and then took a necessary `value` or it's `[index]`

Comment: exampleMap.forEach((value, key) => str.includes(key) ? console.log(str + value) : null)

Comment: @Colin, it's deserved to become an answer! Could you post it below, please?

Comment: @AlexZeDim exampleMap.forEach((value, key) => str.includes(key)&&console.log(str + value)) even shorter. inspired by palash's answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use forEach to iterate map and check if key included in the string

```js
let str = 'James never fly to Dubai'

let exampleMap = new Map([
    ['Sasha', ' goes to school'],
    ['James', ' goes to college'],
    ['Kevin', ' goes to work'],
]);

exampleMap.forEach((value, key) => str.includes(key)&&console.log(str + value))
```

Answer (score 1):

To get O(n) lookup time, `.entries()` and `.includes` won't help you. Instead you would've to iterate the string somehow, e.g. splitting by words (which seems to work in your case):

```
 string.split(" ").some(word => exampleMap.has(word))
```

Comment: Yea, it's useful. But as I know `.has` returns `Boolean` true/false. So right after receiving `true` from it, I should also find an `[index] of match. (That isn't a problem for me)

Comment: You could `.find` and `.get` too.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the `exampleMap.entries()` to an array and then apply array `.some()` method like this:

```js
let string = 'James never fly to Dubai'

let exampleMap = new Map([
    ['Sasha', ' goes to school'],
    ['James', ' goes to college'],
    ['Kevin', ' goes to work'],
]);

[...exampleMap.entries()].some(([k,v]) => string.includes(k) && console.log(string, v))
```