# Reactjs : How to check if data exist in a list

Tags: reactjs

I have list that looks like this :

{1: "a", 2: "a", 3: "c", 4: "c"}

I want to check if there is "c" in that list. This is how part of my code looks :

```
answer= {1: "a", 2: "a", 3: "c", 4: "c"}

answer[indexString as keyof typeof answer] = value;

if ("c" in answer) {
   console.log("true");
}
```

I don't know why it only check the id *1,2,3,4* value not the string *"a","b", "c"*. Really appreciate if anyone could help me on this

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check if a value exists in an object using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35948669/how-to-check-if-a-value-exists-in-an-object-using-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check if certain value is present in the object. You can do the following,

```
answer= {1: "a", 2: "a", 3: "c", 4: "c"};

if(Object.values(answer).includes("c")){
 console.log("true");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What you have is an object, not a list. To check if some vale exist in the values of an object use [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) function that creates a list of values. And then check if the need value is present in it: `Object.values(answer).includes("c")`

Answer (score 1):

Did you try using

> `Object.values(answer).includes("c");`